# C# - Select Lines of TextBox depending on position of click

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm working on a C# Windows Form Application where I have a non-editable `TextBox` displaying the details of several objects of a custom class `Note`.

`Note` has an overridden `ToString()` method that outputs all the attributes with a label on a separate line, so the string returned by a note object would look like this:

"Recorded At: 12:00

Recorded By: Steve

Note Content: hello world"

I want each of these attributes to appear on a separate line in the `TextBox`, and there will be an extra blank line between the end of one note's data and the start of the next.

This all works fine, what I want to implement now is ability to 'select' notes from the textbox using the cursor.

Ideally what I would like is that if any of the 3 lines containing a note's data are clicked in, all three of the lines relating to that note are highlighted.

Does anyone know if this is possible using a `TextBox`? If so, I would I go about it?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: A text box is not really suitable for this task.

Comment: I did also wonder about using a Listbox, but I was struggling to split the string over 3 lines. Would this be easier to work around than using a textbox? @CathalMF

Comment: Maybe post your listbox code and we can try and fix it.

Comment: @marcuthh you dont need to do anything special. just set the `Height` property of items of listbox to something larger so it can contain 3 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a custom FlowLayoutPanel which does what you want.

Each time a "note" is clicked it raises the NoteClick event and in the event handler i just select the text from the textbox.

You can change the formatting of the TextBox if you want. I made them look like a label.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    

            noteFlow1.NoteClick += new NoteFlow.ClickHandler(noteFlow1_NoteClick);

            noteFlow1.Add("Hello" + Environment.NewLine + "Hello2" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            noteFlow1.Add("Hello" + Environment.NewLine + "Hello2" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            noteFlow1.Add("Hello" + Environment.NewLine + "Hello2" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            noteFlow1.Add("Hello" + Environment.NewLine + "Hello2" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            noteFlow1.Add("Hello" + Environment.NewLine + "Hello2" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        void noteFlow1_NoteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox sndr = sender as TextBox;
            sndr.SelectAll();
        }
    }


    public class NoteFlow : FlowLayoutPanel
    {
        public delegate void ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
        public event ClickHandler NoteClick;

        public NoteFlow()
        {
            base.AutoScroll = true;
            base.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
        }

        public void Add(string noteText)
        {
            TextBox TextBox1 = new TextBox();
            TextBox1.Multiline = true;
            TextBox1.Text = noteText;
            TextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            TextBox1.BorderStyle = 0;
            TextBox1.BackColor = this.BackColor;
            TextBox1.TabStop = false;
            Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(TextBox1.Text, TextBox1.Font);
            TextBox1.Width = size.Width;
            TextBox1.Height = size.Height;
            TextBox1.Click += new EventHandler(TextBox1_Click);
            base.Controls.Add(TextBox1);
        }

        void TextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (NoteClick != null)
            {
                NoteClick(sender, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This has turned out to be exactly what I want. Thank you for your efforts!